# How Do I Select Results Based on Newest Results in Another Table Without Any Duplicates?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables: groups and group_activity. The structure of groups is

> id int(11) unsigned Auto Increment
>   creator varchar(15)
>   name    varchar(30)
>   description text
>   join_policy tinyint(1)
>   avatar  varchar(500)
>   date_created    varchar(13)

And the structure of the group_activity table is

> id int(11) Auto Increment
>   group_id    int(11)
>   action  tinytext

The column *group_id* in the **group_activity** table relates to *id* in the **groups** table so when you go to the page of the specific group, you see all the activity relating to it.

I am building a groups feature for a site I'm an Administrator on, and one of the things on the main page of the groups is a "recently active groups" thing. Maybe I am doing this wrong, and if I am can someone please tell me the best way?

What I am currently trying to do is display groups ordered by the most recent result in group_activity, but not show any duplicate group names aka *name varchar(30)* from the groups table. I'm new to selecting/filtering results based on results in multiple tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a self join for your activity table by getting the max of auto_increment column per group

```
select g.*,ga.*
from group_activity ga
join (select max(id) id , group_id from group_activity group by group_id ) gaa
on(ga.id=gaa.id)
join groups g on (ga.group_id =g.id)
```

Subquery gaa will give the max id i.e most recent id for each group and you join again as self join with `group_activity` table to get action from your table and in the last join your group table

**Edit from comments**

You can give unique aliases to your select columns as

```
select g.*,ga.id AS ga_id ,ga.group_id AS ga_group_id,ga.action AS ga_action
from group_activity ga
join (select max(id) id , group_id from group_activity group by group_id ) gaa
on(ga.id=gaa.id)
join groups g on (ga.group_id =g.id)
```

Now in your php code when you fetch data the data information you can use as

```
$row['id'] <---- Belongs to id of group
$row['creator '] <---- Belongs to creator column of group
$row['ga_id '] <---- Belongs to id of group_activity 
$row['ga_group_id'] <---- Belongs to group id of group_activity 
$row['ga_action'] <---- Belongs to action column of group_activity
```

Comment: Thank you sir, it worked. Another question: I am displaying the results via mysqli_fetch_array in PHP and want to use the *id* from the **groups** table in a mysqli_num_rows query to get the amount of members. There's groups.id and group_activity.id. How would I display groups.id within $row['']? I'm sure this is very simple. xD Would it have something to do with the AS keyword perhaps? I already tried $row['groups.id']

Comment: @DoctorSatan this ia another question its better to ask new one,also if you want me to post answer on your new question post the link of your new question here so i can look into it

Comment: I will search here (as well as Google) to see if any answers currently exist, rather than wasting space with a new question, but thank you for the advice. If all else fails I will post one. :)

Comment: It worked. Again, thank you for all your help M Khalid Junaid. I'd upvote your answer but unfortunately I don't have enough reputation. :P

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you properly, and you want to order groups in order of actions,
performed in them, you can use this query, it groups activity records by **group_id**, order them by max value of autoincrement field and joins **groups** table.

```
select group_id, MAX(ga.id) AS max_id, g.name
from group_activity ga
left join groups g ON ga.group_id = g.id
group by group_id
order by max_id desc
```

If you don't need specific performed actions, you can just add field **date_last_activity** in **groups** table, updating it on every action in group and you query will become simple

```
select * from groups order by date_last_activity desc;
```

You can do it even if you really need **group_activity** table for other issues, but it will add a bit denormalization to your scheme.

I also have some advices:

- don't use varchar type for date fields, there are much more suitable
  date fields in mysql for this cases.
- if you want to use joins in your scheme, you better create index on
  **group_id** field. It will be very helpful when your table will grow large.

Comment: Thank you for an alternate way to do this. I figured a fairly complex query would be better than wasting extra data by adding date_last_activity, but then again this is on a website with only a couple thousand members. I will keep in mind your advice for the date fields.

One question: what type of index should I use for group_id? I've only ever used UNIQUE before, but it won't work for this because groups have more than 1 action assigned to them. I'm assuming I should use INDEX? Does this provide similar SELECT optimizations like UNIQUE does?

Comment: yep, just simple CREATE INDEX ...
it helps in queries having condition indexed_field = some_value and in joins using this field.

Comment: and also in groupings by indexed fields

Comment: Alright, will do. Thank you for the tip and explanation. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT name FROM groups..
```